# What is "Recipe for target 'gconfig' failed" mean when I do "make xconfig" in Linux terminal?

Tags: linux, terminal, linux-device-driver

I am really new on Linux drivers and I am trying to Compile Linux kernel 2.6,

I did these steps so far on my Linux 4.0

1)
I got Latest Linux kernel code for 2.x.y.z and Extract tar (.tar.bz3) file

2) Installed gcc,

```
apt-get install gcc
```

3)Try to make below but all of them occurred with error:

```
make menuconfig

make xconfig

make gconfig
```

Error:

```
root@kiarash-VirtualBox:~/Desktop/linux-2.6.9# make gconfig
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
scripts/basic/fixdep.c: In function â€˜trapsâ€™:
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:368:2: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
  if (*(int *)test != INT_CONF) {
  ^
scripts/basic/fixdep.c:370:4: warning: dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules [-Wstrict-aliasing]
    *(int *)test);
    ^
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/split-include
scripts/basic/split-include.c: In function â€˜mainâ€™:
scripts/basic/split-include.c:133:6: warning: ignoring return value of â€˜fgetsâ€™, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
      fgets(old_line, buffer_size, fp_target);
      ^
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/docproc
*
* Unable to find the GTK+ installation. Please make sure that
* the GTK+ 2.0 development package is correctly installed...
* You need gtk+-2.0, glib-2.0 and libglade-2.0.
*
  HOSTCC  scripts/kconfig/conf.o
scripts/kconfig/conf.c: In function â€˜conf_stringâ€™:
scripts/kconfig/conf.c:164:20: warning: variable â€˜helpâ€™ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  const char *def, *help;
                    ^
scripts/kconfig/conf.c: In function â€˜conf_symâ€™:
scripts/kconfig/conf.c:198:6: warning: variable â€˜typeâ€™ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int type;
      ^
scripts/kconfig/conf.c: In function â€˜conf_choiceâ€™:
scripts/kconfig/conf.c:273:6: warning: variable â€˜typeâ€™ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
  int type;
      ^
scripts/kconfig/conf.c: In function â€˜conf_askvalueâ€™:
scripts/kconfig/conf.c:94:3: warning: ignoring return value of â€˜fgetsâ€™, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
   fgets(line, 128, stdin);
   ^
scripts/kconfig/conf.c: In function â€˜conf_choiceâ€™:
scripts/kconfig/conf.c:350:4: warning: ignoring return value of â€˜fgetsâ€™, declared with attribute warn_unused_result [-Wunused-result]
    fgets(line, 128, stdin);
    ^
make[1]: *** No rule to make target 'scripts/kconfig/.tmp_gtkcheck', needed by 'scripts/kconfig/gconf.o'.  Stop.
Makefile:429: recipe for target 'gconfig' failed
make: *** [gconfig] Error 2
```

Please help me to undrestand!

Comment: Sorry, but this Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on http://unix.stackexchange.com  OR http://superuser.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here. Good luck

Comment: Did you ever read what it stated: *Unable to find the GTK+ installation. Please make sure that the GTK+ 2.0 development package is correctly installed... You need gtk+-2.0, glib-2.0 and libglade-2.0.*???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

write below in your terminal in order to install gtk2.0 and libgtk2.0-dev

```
sudo apt-get install gtk2.0

sudo apt-get install build-essential libgtk2.0-dev
```